# Swift: Is it possible to type erase a return type for use in a collection

Tags: swift, type-erasure

So here's something that's been bugging me for a while and I've been trying to find a good pattern to use. The problem occurs when I need to create a list of items that conform to a protocol, that has an associated type. For example:

```swift
protocol Setting {
    associatedtype Value
    var value: Value
} 

struct ProjectSetting<T>: Setting {
    var value: T
}

let setting1 = ProjectSetting(value: 1)
let setting1 = ProjectSetting(value: "abc")
```

The problem occurs when then trying to store `ProjectSetting` instances in an array.

```swift
let settings: /* ??? */ = [ProjectSetting(value: 1), ProjectSetting(value: "abc")]
```

Swift won't let me do `let settings: [Setting] = ...` because of the associated type, and it won't let me do `let settings: [ProjectSetting<Any>] = ...` either.

So I need to do some sort of type erasure to hide the type of the setting, but everything I've tried ends up needing the generic type exposed. I've tried to type erase by wrapping closures but I end up either exposing an `Any` or the generic type again.

Does anyone have a technique for wrapping a generic protocol so that it can be stored in an array regardless of the type being used?

Comment: Let's suppose that you could do this, what would be the compile time type `settings[x].value`? It has to be `Any`, right? You can't "not expose an `Any`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully the following approach fits your needs. I did it only for getter just to simplify the demo, but the idea should be clear.

*Note*: used Xcode 11.2 / Swift 5.1 / Catalina

So here is your original entities

```
protocol Setting {
    associatedtype Value
    var value: Value { get }
}

struct ProjectSetting<T>: Setting {
    let value: T
}
```

Now we need some helper protocols to hide your type differences, aka type erasers

```
private protocol TypeErasing {
    var value: Any { get }
}

private struct TypeEraser<V: Setting>: TypeErasing {
    let orinal: V
    var value: Any {
        return self.orinal.value
    }
}
```

Now the core entity that wraps your concrete implementors holding different type values, but still allows to use those values and be stored in standard containers

```
struct AnySetting : Setting {
    typealias Value = Any
    private let eraser: TypeErasing
    init<V>(_ setting: V) where V:Setting {
        eraser = TypeEraser(orinal: setting)
    }

    var value: Any {
        return eraser.value
    }
}
```

Now testing your expectation

```
let settings = [AnySetting(ProjectSetting(value: 1)), AnySetting(ProjectSetting(value: "abc"))]


if let value = settings[0].value as? Int {
    print("Stored value: \(value)")
}
if let value = settings[1].value as? String {
    print("Stored value: \(value)")
}
```

PlayGround output

```
Stored value: 1
Stored value: abc
```

Comment: Thanks @asperi I was hoping I'd be able to still get the base types back, but as your example shows, it looks like I'll have to go through `Any` types to make it work.